# How to run method every night on JEE Cluster

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish

I have a Java EE Application running on Glassfish 3.1.2 in a clustered environement.

I want to execute a specific method once a day (i.e. delete some entries from the database).

I created a Timer:

```
@Singleton
public class TimerService {
    @Schedule(second = "0", minute = "0", hour = "0", persistent=false)
    public void runEveryDay() {
        LOG.info("### runEveryDay");
    }
```

When I look into the logs, the method is executed on both cluster nodes. I fear that when executing the method on both nodes at the same time I might run into problems because of stale data.

Is there a way that the method is executed only on one node? Or can I synchronize the methods somehow?

Comment: I had this problem, too.  A better solution would be to schedule the nightly batch separate from the Java EE container, scheduled by the OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your timer to be persistent. It then should only execute on one server node in the cluster.

Answer (score 1):

You can protect against concurrent execution by using a preloaded database row as a transactional lock.

Write a JobLockService something like:

```
@Stateless
public class JobLockService {

     @Resource
     private DataSource serializableDS;

     @TransactionAttribute(REQUIRES_NEW)
     public boolean jobLockAcquired() {
          // select jobLock record for update when flag = 0 and set flag
          return true if record selected otherwise false
     }

     @TransactionAttribute(REQUIRES_NEW)
     public void releaseJobLock() {
          // reset jobLock record flag back to 0
     }

}
```

and then provide it your singleton:

```
@Singleton
public class TimerService {

    @EJB
    private JobLockService jobLockService;

    @Schedule(second = "0", minute = "0", hour = "0", persistent=false)
    public void runEveryDay() {
        if (jobLockService.jobLockAcquired()) {
            try {
                 LOG.info("### runEveryDay");
            } finally {
                 jobLockService.releaseJobLock();
            }
        } else {
            log.info("Job already running elsewhere");
        }
    }
```

Configure a special datasource in your server that is configured with it's transaction isolation level set to [TRANSACTION_SERIALIZABLE](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#TRANSACTION_SERIALIZABLE) in order to prevent concurrency problems. (You would not normally use this setting because it's high load concurrent performance sucks)

The use of [REQUIRES_NEW](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/TransactionAttributeType.html#REQUIRES_NEW) transactions on the JobLockService methods will prevent blocking problems.